# No overload for '<method>' matches delegate '<delegate>'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

My "Security" assembly includes this code:

```
    public delegate void InteropEventDelegate(InteropEventType etype, string data, string data2, string data3);
    public event InteropEventDelegate InteropEvent;
```

A second assembly references my "Security" assembly, and includes this code:

```
    void LoadSecurity()
    {
        if (!AssemblyIsLocked && Security == null)
        {
            this.Security = new Security.Security(UnlockCode);
            this.Security.InteropEvent += new Security.Security.InteropEventDelegate(Security_InteropEvent);
        }
    }

    void Security_InteropEvent(InteropEventType etype, string data, string data2, string data3)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Security_InteropEvent was generated by IntelliSense, and has the correct signature, but I get error "No overload for 'Security_InteropEvent' matches delegate 'Security.Security.InteropEventDelegate'".  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have another type called `InteropEventType` declared somewhere? That would make the first parameter of `Security_InteropEvent` a different type to the first parameter of `InteropEventDelegate`.

While I'm mentioning names, I would *strongly* advise you not to give the same name to a type and a namespace. Eric Lippert has a [whole blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/namespaces/) about the perils of this. (I'm talking about `Security.Security`, which I originally assumed to be a poorly named namespace, until I saw you were calling a constructor on it.)

Comment: I second this recommendation. The simple excerpt `Security = new Security.Security` has three meanings for the same word!

Comment: Yes, I was sharing an ENUMS.CS file between the assemblies, where InteropEventType is defined.  Even though it's defined identically in both places, I guess it's treated as two separate types.  Is there a way to share an enum between assemblies so that something like what I had would work?

Comment: @PahJoker: You "share" the enum by making one assembly refer to the other, basically. Never define a type in two different assemblies - it's bound to cause problems.